# Ringing output flyback power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm meeting with problem with flyback power supply. 
[image: Schematic]

[image: Top layer]

[image: Bottom layer]

[image: ALL layer]

And this is problems at output:[image: Output_1]

[image: Zoom OUT_1]

[image: Main PROBLEM]

I read some documents online and i think it's ringing of second winding but i try to place 10uF and 100nF ceramic capacitor front and behind L2 but it's also. Frequency of ringing about 4Mhz. Someone can give me some solutions for this issue. Thanks!

*Update 01/12/2017
This is product: 
[image: Top 3D]

[![Bot 3D][9]][9]

[![REAL][10]][10]

All of picture was measured at full load.

*Update 01/12/2017 continue...:

*Update 02/12/2017: Maybe i got the source of problem, i try with a isolated AC power supplies and the amplitude of ringing reduced. And i will try more times to give a conclusion. Someone can give me some advice about reducing noise from AC power supply?
* Update 02/12/2017: The issue solved, the cause is common mode (CM) noise, i put a common choke coil and it worked fine. Thank everyone!

Comment: You don't tell how you measure (e.g. low inductance or with the big gnd antenna)

Comment: Watch this one, follow and report back. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Edel3eduRj4

Comment: Also, why no ground plane? Why make it difficult for yourself? What's the ESR and ESL of C5? Are you planning on a cutout of the board or how do you propose to meet creepage requirements between primary to secondary?

Comment: Experienced members very easily suspect classical oscilloscope usage errors because you have no photos that show exactly how the grounds of your probes are connected. Please, provide a photo of your probe connections to stop thinking that you are a beginner. 4Mhz ringing can be a resonance in L2. It needs about 300pF self-capacitance and a good initiating pulse. C5 should have low inductance capacitor in parallel to keep that pulse low.  What happens if you add a) some load to the output? b) a piece of metal between T1 and L2 to reduce coupling between the inductors?

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Pls checked with my update.

Comment: @winny : This product is tiny and i think it don't have space to pour GND. Partnumber of C5: EKMQ160ELL102MJC5S, ESR is very low. I will try cutout the board if it can solve. Did you meet before?

Comment: @user287001 : Pls checked my update, i think it's not problem from resonance of L2, because i shorted L2 and it's also. C5 partnumber: EKMQ160ELL102MJC5S.

Comment: Of course you have space! What's your primary to secondary creepage? Those two tracks looks very close to each others. EMC comes to mind too with no ground pour nor filters.

Comment: @winny: PLS checked my update...

Comment: Won't pass CE or UL! Set spacing constraints in your CAD system.

Comment: Make your measurements like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G43Kf.jpg). Also, don't hesitate to use copper pour areas for GND. You should also minimize the track impedances by using thicker tracks *(Using copper areas instead of tracks is also a good practice)*.

Comment: It seems VERY starange that noise level modulated with 100 Hz (first waveform). 
Have you obsered waveforms at primary and secondary windings?

Comment: @winny: How is a best spacing? check my update, pls.

Comment: @RohatKılıç: I have tried before, it's also. Check my update. pls

Comment: @EugeneK: The waveforms of primary and secondary windings are not strange, i will update, but with 100Hz waveforms, i think it is level 2 of 50Hz of AC power supplier. Check my update, pls.

Comment: "Best"? Are you not aware there are legal requirements for electrical safety?